# Transferring data based on criteria in another column in the row in vba

Tags: excel, vba

How would i copy data in the 1st and 2nd columns in a sheet based on the colour (3 available colours) of the 3rd column to 3 separate tables in Sheet 2 that are based on the 3 different colours?

Comment: Hi Sam, how to copy cells based on color is well documented here. Have you done any research yet? This is not a code writing service so you will need to show us your attempts/code and explain what specific issue you are having. After, we are more than happy to help! GL

Answer (score 0):

Sam, I would say to use the *[ColorIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm551074)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)* property to gather your range. You can then surf through the Worksheet and create a Collection or an Array, then go from there. And, since you barely have any details about your *ask*, I'm just attempting this to give you a rolling start...

```
Option Explicit

Sub CollectColors()

Dim cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NoColor As Variant
Dim rngColors As Range
Dim arr_addresses() As String
Dim x As Integer

'set variables
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
NoColor = -4142
x = 1

'acquire array of cell addresses with some color
For Each cell In ws.UsedRange
    If cell.Interior.ColorIndex <> NoColor Then
        ReDim Preserve arr_addresses(1 To x)
        arr_addresses(x) = cell.Address
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```